# Images only loading in bx slider when inspect element, bx slider added in bootstrap modal, is that css issue?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added bx slider in bootstrap modal and show that modal on click of element, but problem is that images are not loading without inspect element in browser, this is link of site where I have put this http://dev.makemyloans.com/

And in bottom you can see I have added "Quote Loan" link, by pressing this modal appearing and bx slider in it loading as well, but images not showing, and when open inspect element in browser window, images showing. Is that CSS issue?

Is there anyone who can look into this and help me out.

Comment: looks like its not about inspect element. window resize is loading the image.

Comment: @techLove But I only adding text in place of these images, that is also not showing without inspect element

Comment: @techLove yes you are right, its about resize window, when resize browser window its showing, but its also same with adding just text instead  of images

Answer (score 0):

I have find out solution of this issue with different way, as I am using bootstrap so I have added its inbuilt carousel in modal box and its working fine now. So I have removed Bx-Slider and add Bootstrap Carousel on its place.